# Is there a good document template for making business cards?

Tags: templates, business-cards

Is there a good document template for making business cards?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The [`labels`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/labels/labels.pdf) package is excellent for this, if you want to hand-craft the layout within the card.

---

Thanks, @MartinScharrer, for your excellent suggestion. Here's a small(?), imperfect example for people to play with:

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[a4paper,9pt,oneside,landscape]{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[newdimens]{labels}
\setmainfont[Numbers={OldStyle,Monospaced}]{Brill}
\setsansfont{Source Sans Pro Light}
\LabelCols=5%
\LabelRows=2%
\LeftPageMargin=13.0mm%
\RightPageMargin=8.0mm%
\TopPageMargin=16.5mm%
\BottomPageMargin=16.5mm%
\InterLabelColumn=1.5mm%
\InterLabelRow=5.0mm%
\LeftLabelBorder=6mm%
\RightLabelBorder=6mm%
\TopLabelBorder=7mm%
\BottomLabelBorder=6mm%
\numberoflabels=10%
\LabelGridtrue%  <-- or \LabelGridfalse
\newcommand{\phonei}{+44\textendash2323\textendash323232}
\newcommand{\phoneii}{+44\textendash7999\textendash797979}
\newcommand{\emaili}{carlos@dickens.org}
%
\begin{document}
\addresslabel[\fboxsep=5mm]{%
    {%
    \raggedright%
    {\Large\scshape Charles Dickens}\\[1ex]
    \textit{Narrative Typography}\\
    \vspace{4ex}
    48 Doughty Street\\
    Holborn\\
    London\\
    {\textsc{uk: wc1n 2lx}}\\   
    \vspace{4ex}%
    \hrule%
    \vspace{4ex}%
    \hfill{\small\textit{\phonei}}\\%
    \hfill{\small\textit{\phoneii}}\\[2ex]%
    \hfill{\small\sffamily\textbf{\emaili}}%
    }%
}
\end{document}
```

And here's a bit of the output. Note that I've included the label borders, which I wouldn't do for 'production':

[image]

---

A rather late, and probably obvious, afterthought: although PC printers for "amateurs" generally produce consistent positioning on the page, the *absolute* position of the PDF sheet when printed *may* not match the exact boundaries of the paper. So if you're using expensive precut visiting card sheets, print a proof first, to check alignment with the actual cards.

Comment: It would be great if you could add a simple code example with a result image to your answer. Other people could use it as a starting point.

Comment: Wouldn't it be cleaner to have one document for the actual card and then another which prints multiple on one sheet?  Of course, respecting the backside of the card.

Comment: @FrederickNord If it were several different cards, all with the same format, yes. In my case it's just multiple copies of a single card, so the split into two files is bet extra work in this example.

Comment: How do you define the size of a card?  The "normal" business card size seems to be 85mm by 54mm.  And they tend to have a backside. That doesn't seem to be possible to the package.

Comment: Well, I did it in this case by careful measuring on the card stock. For the back side, I defined another set of cards, as another page, and printed on the back, swapping the corresponding page margins to allow for the paper's going through the printer 'backwards'

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for the fix. No idea what went wrong there...

Comment: @Brent.Longborough just one of 7000 postings corrupted by the site but not fixed by them so fixing a few at a time by hand https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7168/double-backslashes-disappear-from-code

Comment: @Brent.Longborough On a related note, how do I get the Brill font?

Answer (score 23):

Packages like »[bizcard](http://ctan.org/pkg/bizcard)« and »[ticket](http://ctan.org/pkg/ticket)« come to my mind. For some inspiration you can take a look at the code of the file "ex_vcard.tex" that is shipped with the latter one.

```
%%%%
%
% ticket.sty example file for visiting cards
%
%%%%
% use the corresponding paper size for your ticket definition
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{letter}

% load ticket.sty with the appropriate ticket definition
\usepackage[zw32010,crossmark]{ticket}

% load misc stuff
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}

% define something
\definecolor{uni}{rgb}{.3019,.7216,.7019}

% make your default ticket. \ticketdefault is somewhat like a background
% here it is empty, because we use different tickets for the front an
% the back of our card
\renewcommand{\ticketdefault}{%
}

% now what do you like to put in your ticket
\newcommand{\vcardfront}[5]{\ticket{%
    \put( 63, 5){\includegraphics[width=40mm,angle=90,origin=bl]{ifmlogoc}}
    \put( 63.2, 2){\color{uni}your logo}
    \put( 5, 13){\color{uni}\line(1,0){56}}
    \put( 7, 10){\small your company}
    \put( 7,6.5){\small street 1}
    \put( 7,  3){\small xxxxx city and state}
    \put( 7, 24){\small phone:}
    \put( 7, 20){\small fax:}
    \put(6,40){\bfseries\LARGE #1}
    \put(7,36){#2}
    \put(15,24){\small #3}
    \put(15,20){\small #4}
    \put( 7,16){\small #5}
 }}

\newcommand{\vcardback}[1]{\ticket{%
    \put( 7, 26){\small private:}
    \put( 5, 23){\color{uni}\line(1,0){56}}
    \put( 7,19){\small%
        \begin{minipage}[t]{50mm}%
          {#1}\hss%
        \end{minipage}}%
}}

% a counter, which makes life easier...
\newcounter{numcards}

\begin{document}
\sffamily

% ten cards for the front
\whiledo{\thenumcards<10}{%
  \stepcounter{numcards}%
  \vcardfront{Mr. X}{Degree/Profession}{+YY/XXXX/ZZZ ZZ ZZ}{+YY/XXXX/ZZZ ZZ ZZ}{yourmail@your-provider.xxx}}

\setcounter{numcards}{0}

% and ten for the backside
\whiledo{\thenumcards<10}{%
  \stepcounter{numcards}%
  \vcardback{phone: ---/HH HH HHH\\fax: ---/HH HH HHH\\homestreet 7\\everywhere}}
\end{document}
```

The pictures show the front (left) and the back (right) of the cards.

---

[image][image]

Comment: It would be great if you could add a simple code example with a result image to your answer. Other people could use it as a starting point.

Comment: Why is it that if I change `ifmlogoc` it complains file not found?

Comment: @puk: It goes without saying the the chosen image file has to be either in the TeX installation tree or in the current working directory together with the concerned source file. Or it requires the correct path to the file. Otherwise it will not be found.

Comment: @ThorstenDonig I guess what I should have really asked is *Where is `ifmlogoc` located*

Comment: @puk: Open a [command line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface), type `kpsewhich ifmlogoc.pdf` and confirm with enter. You will get the complete path. If there's no output, you need to install the »[ifmslide](http://ctan.org/pkg/ifmslide)« package.

Comment: How would I right-align the phone numbers, for example. It seems I need to manually tweak the coordinates every time I make a change :-/

Answer (score 7):

You could also just roll your own by making the whole document a `tikzpicture` and placing the text with `\node` commands.

Comment: Sounds promising. Do you happen to have an example?  And then for a backside?  And then how to print a few of them on a single sheet of paper?

Comment: @FrederickNord: In the six years since I made that half-baked answer I still haven't had the occasion to do so.  Sorry. :-)

Comment: Have a look at the repository by Olivier Pieters (https://github.com/opieters/business-card), which uses this technique.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン that's a nice addition.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, and i couldn't find a good template for my needs, so i made my own template from scratch. It supports duplex (double-side) printing, you can choose different languages for each side, and I tried to make it simple and clean, so that other people could easily extend it. Maybe you find it useful.

https://github.com/aorthey/business-cards-latex

[image: Latex Template Front]

Comment: You don't support backsides, though, right?

Comment: @FrederickNord yes front and backside is supported.

Answer (score 1):

You could also just roll your own by making the whole document a `pspicture` and placing the text with `\rput` commands.