# sticky labels with image and text

Tags: graphics, sticky-labels

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Is there a good document template for making business cards?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4693/is-there-a-good-document-template-for-making-business-cards)

I need to create a A4 page with sticky labels on it.

The page should look like this:

```
-------------------
|     |     |     |
|  1  |  2  |  3  |
-------------------
|     |     |     |
|  4  |  5  |  6  |
-------------------
|     |     |     |
|  7  |  8  |  9  |
-------------------
|     |     |     |
| 10  | 11  | 12  |
-------------------
|     |     |     |
| 13  | 14  | 15  |
-------------------
```

The label size is 70mm x 50mm.

One label looks like this:
(x the image)
(y the text)

```
-----------------------
| xxxxxx              |
| xxxxxx MsShort Name |
| xxxxxx              |
-----------------------

-----------------------
| xxxxxx              |
| xxxxxx MsVeryLong   |
| xxxxxx Name         |
-----------------------
```

If the text is too long it should continue on the second line.

Has someone an idea?

This is my code so far:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\paperheight297mm
\paperwidth210mm

\textheight297mm
\textwidth180mm

\topmargin-25.4mm
\voffset0in
\oddsidemargin-17.5mm
\evensidemargin-17.5mm
\hoffset0in

\marginparsep0in
\marginparwidth0in

\headheight0in
\headsep0in

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{p{60mm} p{60mm} p{60mm}}
\vspace{18pt} \raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[height=35mm]{test.png}} \raisebox{-\height}{\raisebox{-\height}[15mm]{Some Name}} & \vspace{15pt} \raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[height=35mm]{test.png}} \raisebox{-\height}{\raisebox{-\height}[15mm]{Some Name}} & \vspace{15pt} \raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[height=35mm]{test.png}} \raisebox{-\height}{\raisebox{-\height}[15mm]{Some Name}} \\[50.8mm]
\vspace{15pt} \raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[height=35mm]{test.png}} \raisebox{-\height}{\raisebox{-\height}[15mm]{Some Name}} & \vspace{15pt} \raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[height=35mm]{test.png}} \raisebox{-\height}{\raisebox{-\height}[15mm]{Some Name}} & \vspace{15pt} \raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[height=35mm]{test.png}} \raisebox{-\height}{\raisebox{-\height}[15mm]{Some Name}} \\[50.8mm]
\vspace{15pt} \raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[height=35mm]{test.png}} \raisebox{-\height}{\raisebox{-\height}[15mm]{Some Name}} & \vspace{15pt} \raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[height=35mm]{test.png}} \raisebox{-\height}{\raisebox{-\height}[15mm]{Some Name}} & \vspace{15pt} \raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[height=35mm]{test.png}} \raisebox{-\height}{\raisebox{-\height}[15mm]{Some Name}} \\[50.8mm]
\vspace{15pt} \raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[height=35mm]{test.png}} \raisebox{-\height}{\raisebox{-\height}[15mm]{Some Name}} & \vspace{15pt} \raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[height=35mm]{test.png}} \raisebox{-\height}{\raisebox{-\height}[15mm]{Some Name}} & \vspace{15pt} \raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[height=35mm]{test.png}} \raisebox{-\height}{\raisebox{-\height}[15mm]{Some Name}} \\[50.8mm]
\vspace{15pt} \raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[height=35mm]{test.png}} \raisebox{-\height}{\raisebox{-\height}[15mm]{Some Name}} & \vspace{15pt} \raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[height=35mm]{test.png}} \raisebox{-\height}{\raisebox{-\height}[15mm]{Some Name}} & \vspace{15pt} \raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[height=35mm]{test.png}} \raisebox{-\height}{\raisebox{-\height}[15mm]{Some Name}} \\[50.8mm]
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

But if the text is too long it just jumps at the end of the cell. How can I fix that?

Comment: Can you replace the `xxxxx` and `yyyyy` with something more meaningful? It would be great if you can show a long text situation too. Lastly, what's the significance of the sticky labels. Any cell format on paper would do or not?

Comment: Okay, I replaced the 'yy' but I can't replace the 'xx' with an actual image.

70mm x 50mm is the size of the labels, so there is no border on the right or on the left side of the paper. The top border is 24mm and the bottom border is 23mm. There is no space between the labels.

Comment: You cannot print a paper without margins in standard printers so you need to give some space. So, it's a matter of making a table.

Comment: I added my try..

Comment: You might want to read [Is there a good document template for making business cards?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4693/is-there-a-good-document-template-for-making-business-cards)