# Print business cards in LaTeX

Tags: xetex

I am trying to print a business card that I develop in LaTeX, using templates that I found on the web and combined to fit my needs. I am using XeLaTeX to compile it, since it uses different fonts.

My problem: the template produces a single pdf file with the card, which has dimension 3.5" x 2" inches. I want to print several of this cards on each A4 page. Any suggestions? Thanks.

(I am not a LaTeX expert)

Comment: related (but no luck yet): http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/142447/36821

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Please register on this site, and edit your question to provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) starting from `\documentclass...` until `\end{document}`.

Comment: probably also interesting: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4693/is-there-a-good-document-template-for-making-business-cards

Answer (score 5):

Here's an answer using the `labels` package. Hopefully, the way you will need to tweak it is obvious...

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[a4paper,9pt,oneside,landscape]{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[newdimens]{labels}
\setmainfont[Numbers={OldStyle,Monospaced}]{Brill}
\setsansfont{Source Sans Pro Light}
\LabelCols=5%
\LabelRows=2%
\LeftPageMargin=13.0mm%
\RightPageMargin=8.0mm%
\TopPageMargin=16.5mm%
\BottomPageMargin=16.5mm%
\InterLabelColumn=1.5mm%
\InterLabelRow=5.0mm%
\LeftLabelBorder=6mm%
\RightLabelBorder=6mm%
\TopLabelBorder=7mm%
\BottomLabelBorder=6mm%
\numberoflabels=10%
\LabelGridfalse
\LabelGridtrue
\newcommand{\phonei}{+44\textendash2323\textendash323232}
\newcommand{\phoneii}{+44\textendash7999\textendash797979}
\newcommand{\emaili}{carlos@dickens.org}
%
\begin{document}
\addresslabel[\fboxsep=5mm]{%
    {%
    \raggedright%
    {\Large\scshape Charles Dickens}\\[1ex]
    \textit{Narrative Typography}\\
    \vspace{4ex}
    48 Doughty Street\\
    Holborn\\
    London\\
    {\textsc{uk: wc1n 2lx}}\\   
    \vspace{4ex}%
    \hrule%
    \vspace{4ex}%
    \hfill{\small\textit{\phonei}}\\%
    \hfill{\small\textit{\phoneii}}\\[2ex]%
    \hfill{\small\sffamily\textbf{\emaili}}%
    }%
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an answer using the pdfpages package (main refer to pdf document containing the single card visit)

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{letter}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
    \includepdf[pages={1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},nup=2x5,frame]{main}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

So first your compile one pdf file containing only one business card. Then you need to compile another file that produces 10 business cards on a a4 page (5x2 matrix) the code is.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\verticalcards}{5}
\textwidth 22.00cm % 21.59cm
\textheight 27.94cm
\topmargin -1.75in % was -1.0

\headheight 0in
\headsep 0in
\oddsidemargin -0.5in % ok fits A4 paper

\usepackage{pstricks} % allows using PSTricks!!  Remove if you don't have it.
\usepackage{pst-node} % nodes in pst

\usepackage{graphics}

\pagestyle{empty} % removes page numbers

\begin{document}
\noindent
\setlength{\unitlength}{1in}
\begin{picture}(8.5,11)(0.0,0.3937) % revised for 5 vertical per page
  \thicklines
  \multiput(0,0)(3.64,0.0){2}{ % horizontal (x) motion
     \multiput(0,0)(0.0,2.14){\verticalcards}{ % vertical (y) motion
        \framebox(3.5,2){ % x,y size of box, inches
           \shortstack[1]{
           \includegraphics*{BC/qrGrey.pdf}
           } % end shortstack
        } % end makebox
     } % end multiput
  } % end multiput
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

I compile my single business card with xelatex. However, I compile the previous code with pdflatex. Of course, you need to change "BC/qrGrey.pdf" with your own file.

I just show the output with a zoom out to show you that it's working (5x2 cards on a4 page)

[image]